# Why is :packadd failing in this case?

Tags: neovim, packer

I am trying to reinstall neovim so that all the files are in the config directory of `.config/nvim`.

In my config file which is required by `/home/shadrock/.config/nvim/init.lua`.

The commented `local install_path` did install packer originally; I changed the `install_path` and the `.package_root`.

Can my paths be set as in the config file to install everything in `.config/nvim`?

```
:lua print(vim.o.packpath) 
    /home/shadrock/.config/nvim,/etc/xdg/nvim,/home/shadrock/.local/share/nvim/site,/usr/local/share/nvim/site,/usr/share/nvim/site,/usr/local/share/nvim/runtime,/usr/local/lib/nvim,/usr/share/nvim/site/after,/usr/local/share/nvim/site/after,/home/shadrock/.local/share/nvim/site/after,/etc/xdg/nvim/after,/home/shadrock/.config/nvim/after
```

This is `/home/shadrock/.config/nvim/lua/plugins.lua`:

```
-- NVIM v0.7.2
local fn = vim.fn
-- Automatically install packer
-- local install_path = fn.stdpath("data") .. "/site/pack/packer/start/packer.nvim"
local install_path = "~/.config/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/packer.nvim"
if fn.empty(fn.glob(install_path)) > 0 then
  packer_bootstrap = fn.system({
    "git",
    "clone",
    "--depth",
    "1",
    "https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim",
    install_path,
  })
end
-- Autocommand that reloads neovim whenever you save the plugin.lua file
vim.cmd([[
  augroup packer_user_config
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePost plugins.lua source <afile> | PackerCompile
  augroup end
]])
vim.api.nvim_command("packadd packer.nvim")
-- returns the require for use in `config` parameter of packer's use
-- expects the name of the config file
function get_setup(name)
  return string.format('require("setup/%s")', name)
end
-- Install plugins here
return require("packer").startup({function(use)
-------
-- plugins goes here
------
  if packer_bootstrap then
    require("packer").sync()
  end
  config = {
    package_root = '~/.config/nvim/site/pack',
    display = {
      open_fn = require("packer.util").float,
    },
    profile = {
      enable = true,
      threshold = 1, -- the amount in ms that a plugins load time must be over for it to be included in the profile
    },
  },
})
```

The following error is return on nvim startup:

```
Error detected while processing /home/shadrock/.config/nvim/init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: /home/shadrock/.config/nvim/lua/plugins.lua:28: Vim(packadd):E919: Directory not found in 'packpath': "pack/*/opt/packer.nvim"
    stack traceback:
            [C]: in function 'nvim_command'
            /home/shadrock/.config/nvim/lua/plugins.lua:28: in main chunk
            [C]: in function 'require'
            /home/shadrock/.config/nvim/init.lua:3: in main chunk
Error detected while processing /home/shadrock/.config/nvim/plugin/packer_compiled.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: /home/shadrock/.config/nvim/plugin/packer_compiled.lua:8: Vim(packadd):E919: Directory not found
     in 'packpath': "pack/*/opt/packer.nvim"
    stack traceback:
            [C]: in function 'nvim_command'
            /home/shadrock/.config/nvim/plugin/packer_compiled.lua:8: in main chunk
Press ENTER or type command
```

Comment: Note that your output for `packpath` does not include `~/.config/nvim/site`, so cloning something into a package there won't work.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i tried adding local opt = vim.opt -- to set options

opt.packpath = "~/.config/nvim/site"

Comment: thanks for your reply, i tried adding local opt = vim.opt -- to set options

opt.packpath = "~/.config/nvim/site" to my options.lua file sourced by init.lua, but this didn't add it to packpath, whats the correct way to add a path to packpath ?